# request.user not set in Cloud Code function

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm calling a Cloud Code function from a JavaScript application with a logged-in user, like this:

```
if (Parse.User.current()) { // just to assert there is a logged-in user
  Parse.Cloud.run('foo').then(...);
}
```

In the Cloud Code function I want to access the current user (i.e. the user from whose context the function is called):

```
Parse.Cloud.define('foo', (req, res) => {
  var user = req.user;
  //...
}
```

Unfortunately, `user` is undefined. Is this code supposed to work, or is there an obvious mistake?

P.S.: Using parse-server 2.2.7 (based on parse-server-example) and parse-SDK-JS 1.8.3.

Comment: I have the same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104632/setacls-on-parse-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-> Make sure you update to the latest version of the Parse Server.**

```
sudo npm install parse-server@latest -g
```

At the time of this writing, this should be 2.2.7. 

ref: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/releases

**2-> Make sure the User has a valid session.**


[@hramos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19617/hector-ramos): "request.user will only point to a _User object when the function is triggered by an authenticated user."

ref: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1619

---

```
In other words...., logout and then log back in.
```

Comment: As stated in my question, I'm already using parse-server 2.2.7. I also tried multiple logouts/logins without success. Nevertheless, one day later and after changing lots of code (but nothing that should influence that issue) I do get the current user in the CC request object. So thanks anyway :)

Comment: @dr_barto I'm facing the same issue, but the point is that I'm getting the user back, sometimes, if I reset the server, or not, etc etc... it's happening random.

Comment: I know this issue is checked off, but is it possible this is only happening on the simulator?